# Move block to top

Tags: layout, blocks, rwd

In catalog.xml I have:

```
<catalog_category_layered> 
    <reference name="left"> 
       <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template= "catalog/navigation/left.phtml" />
    </reference>
   ....
 </catalog_category_layered>
```

This left block appears in to the bottom in my responsive theme . But I want to put it at the top. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/page/
And open the .phtml file of the layout you are using.

Then there you will see something like

```
<div class="col-left sidebar">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
</div>
```

Make sure this is in the right place as you will see the different areas of your site here (left-content/main-right) if you use a 3 column layout.

Answer (score 0):

Find where in template implemented

```
$this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav')
```

or

```
$this->getChild('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml()
```

or similar

And move it in your template any place you like

### upd.1

Add this at the end of your controller acltion and share us what you got inside `var/log/layout.log`

```
Mage::log($this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->getSortedChildren(), false, 'layout.log', true)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find it.  'catalog.leftnav' only appears in file.xml :(

Comment: I've updated my answer.